# Use database in two separate applications

Tags: android, sqlite

I know that databases are stored inside the applications data folder how can i access the database from a separate application? Is there a way i can use a database in two separate apk's ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you define a Content Provider in your application then it can be accessed by other applications.

Comment: Where i can find an example ?

Comment: There are lots of examples on the net. You may want to check this overview from Google first http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics.html

Comment: @opc0de The `ContentProvider` is the way to go if you want to access data from another application(that application will have to provide a `ContentProvider`). Besides the official tutorial that Alex provided, there is a simple app in the android samples that you should check out http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/NotePad/index.html .

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to necesarily store the database in the applications data folder; if you put it on the sdcard instead, any app can access it.

Generally you'd probably indeed prefer a server instead, but I felt this was still worth mentioning.

Answer (score 0):

in general, an application's DB can be accessed only by that app. if you want to use the same DB for multiple apps you may want to try using a server instead.